# Microsoft Word Digital Signature Error: We can't read the signature please contact your help desk

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, microsoft-office, certificate, microsoft-word-2013

I create and sign my document in Word 2013 but sometimes when I open the document and check the signature I get the error message: *We can't read the signature. Please contact your help desk.* In the document nothing was edited or changed.

I checked my certificate and everything is ok. The third image on the right is from Word after I sign it.
[image: Valid Certificate]

When I close the document and open it again I often (not always) get the following Error:
[image]

Has anyone experienced something like this in Microsoft Office before ? Why is this happening ? Is there a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I put the Word document on my desktop I realized that the error is not occurring. So I put the document in a folder and realized that the error was always occurring when I opened the document from inside Windows File Explorer when the preview pane was enabled. After I hide the preview pane and open the Word document everything is working fine (the signature is valid). So this must be a bug. So before opening a Word document from Windows File Explorer hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to hide the preview pane.